# Autolayout issue related to scrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, autolayout

I have implemented a ScrollView. 
 
I want to switch between to Views. 
Because it's such simple UI stuff, I just take one Controller and use the hidden attribute to switch between the two views.
Furthermore, I want to position some labels and the views. 
However I can't center them, they are positioned too far on the right side.
I think my constraints are right.
Do you know how to solve this issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not able to view your images. Can you please check and attach it again?

Comment: I have not enough reputation, that's why I added one space tab before ".png". Just remove this space and the two links will work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your layout i’ve tried creating similar kind of layout.

What you need to do is add **Container View** as SubView of UIScrollView.

**Constraints to Scroll View:**

```
You need to set top,reading,trailing and Height constraints.
```

**Constraints to Container View:**

```
You need to set leading,top,trailing and bottom constraints.
You need to set _Height Equally_ to scroll View.
You need to set _Width Equally_ to View.
```

**Constraints to Label:**

1.) Label 2 Constraints:

```
You need to set **Center Horizontally and center Vertically**.
```

2.) Label 1 Constraints:

```
You need to set **Leading space**.

// I’ve set leading space: 10
You also need to set center Y to label 2.
```

3.) Label 3 Constraints:

```
You need to set **Trailing space**.

// I’ve set leading space: 10
You also need to set center Y to label 2.
```

**Constraints to Image View:**

```
You need to set height,width and Vertical Space Constraints.
you also need to set center Horizontally to View.
```

[image]

Hope this help you to solve your problem.